# Encounter error while sending APDU in JCIDE

Tags: smartcard, javacard, apdu

Does anybody here have experience with [JCIDE](https://www.javacardos.com/tools/)?
I tried to send APDU command via DebugShell input box, but I always got the error

> /send: the length should be less than 2.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thx.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across the same problem before. The error you encountered is just because the  command format you sent is wrong.
Use the below format:

> > /send 00A40400

Comment: Both   **/send 00a4040000**    and    **/send "00 a4 04 00 00"** are all correct formats.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Now I can send command w/o any problem.